# Mailgun/Postfix: Relaying Denied

Tags: postfix, smtp, plesk

I have checked the other threads on here and none seem to resolve my issue. I am trying to relay my outgoing emails from Postfix to Mailgun via SMTP. My server is also running Plesk.

My Postfix settings are as follows:

main.cf:

```
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_pass
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = AUTH LOGIN
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_dependent_relayhost
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

sasl_pass:

```
[smtp.mailgun.org]:587 postmaster@mydomain.org:password
```

sender_dependent_relayhost:

```
@mydomain.org [smtp.mailgun.org]:587
```

I can confirm that on Mailgun my domain is DNS verified and the account is SMS/Email verified. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my mistake was that I used smtp**d**_sasl_auth_enable = yes rather than smpt_sasl_auth_enable, and now I know there's a difference between smtp and smtpd...